# What this error mean ? Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'DannyGeneral.OptionsFile' is less accessible than field 'AnimationEditor.Form1

Tags: c#

```
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'DannyGeneral.OptionsFile' is less accessible than field 'AnimationEditor.Form1.setting_file'
```

In Form1 i did:

```
public  OptionsFile setting_file;
```

The error is on the setting_file part.

This is the beginning of the Options_File code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;




namespace DannyGeneral
{
    class OptionsFile
    {

        string path_exe;
        string temp_settings_file;
        string temp_settings_dir;
        string Options_File;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;


    public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(settings))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings));
            }
            File.Create(settings).Close();
        }
        path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
        Options_File = settings; 
    }
```

And In Form1 the top:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;
using unfreez_wrapper;

namespace AnimationEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static string settings_dir;
        private static string settings_file;
        public  OptionsFile setting_file;
```

Comment: @500 - Internal gave you the answer, but a point to bear in mind if you don'r have a modifier (e.g) public, then the out of the`box default in VS is internal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have the type `OptionsFile` itself be public if you want to use it as a `public` property.

[Restrictions on Using Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx03xt0t.aspx)

Comment: Internal but i dont have the type of the OptionsFile or im wrong ? In other programs im using the OptionsFile i did: static OptionsFile settingFile; I didnt understand i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Either mark the class `OptionsFile` as `public` or mark the field `setting_File` as non-public  (`internal` or `private`).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but i get it now for the people who don't get it it should be

```
   namespace DannyGeneral
{
    public class OptionsFile
    {

        string path_exe;
        string temp_settings_file;
        string temp_settings_dir;
        string Options_File;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;
```